# Datatables column.render

Tags: datatables

I am using datatables and would like to over-ride the contents of a cell depending on the value it contains. I am using '1' to flag true in the underlying database and '0' for false. I am attempting to use the Columndefs render function to do this.

Here is my code..

```
xample_table = $('#treatment_list').DataTable(
    {
    select: true,
    destroy: true,
     "order": [ 0, 'desc' ],
        data:json,
        columns : [
            {'data':'treatment_name'},
            {'data':'description'},
             {'data':'measured_in'},
            {'data':'exclusive'}
            ],
       "columnDefs": [
            {      
              "targets":3,
              "data" : "exclusive",
                "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                    if (type === 'display'){
               
                        if (row.exclusive == '0')
                            {
                             return 'No';
                            }
                        else
                         return 'Yes';
                    }
                    
                    
                }
            }
        ]

}

);
```

The problem is I get an erro message from datatables that reads..

> DataTables warning: table id=treatment_list - Requested unknown parameter 'exclusive' for row 0, column 3....

Apart from the error message, it is in fact working.

Comment: You can probably see for yourself, by adding `console.print( data );` and `console.print( row );` to the body of your column render function. If that does not help, then you can  [edit] your question to show us the JSON. (Use F12 to open the browser's console, if you are not familiar with it.)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the advice,but the json was fine and the other variables did not reveal much as I had console logged them before posting here. I did find a solution and am posting it here in case it helps anyone else. This expression works :

```
 "columnDefs": [
        {
            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                if (data =='1') {
                    return "True" ;
                    
                }
                else{
                    return "False" ;
                }
                
            },
            "targets": [3]
        }
    ]
```

In all of the examples I have found, they often included the name of the column being affected and I think this is what caused the error message , whereas - you really just need to include the "targets" : [n] where 'n' is the column number. Perhaps it depends on how the table is constructed ?

Thanks.